# Use some value from terraform file to json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have multiple modules, and in each module there is some image with version updated in locals.tf.
also have descriptor.json file where these same image versions should be updated.

Now,
I wanted to ask if there is any way to use same locals.tf version to version used in descriptor.json.(without hardcoding)

Is there any way we can use variable in descriptor.json maybe?

//locals.tf

```
locals {
  
  xyz_image = "/image.path"
  xyz_image_version = "1.0.0"
}
```

//descriptor.json

```
{
  "service": "xyz",
  "external-resources": {
    "images":
    [
      {
        "name":"xyz_image",
        "version":"1.0.0" //version that should match with locals.tf version
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Are you planning on using the JSON file in other part of terraform code or saving it locally?

Comment: @MarkoE That JSON will be part of deployment. Not using anywhere in TF code

Comment: What kind of a deployment? Can you add some code to the question where you show how you want to use the JSON file?

Comment: @MarkoE This descriptor.json file is used for services in deployment stage. So basically we will be needing JSON format only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you could use the `templatefile` built-in function [1]:

```
resource "local_file" "descriptor" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/descriptor.json.tpl",
    {
       image_version = local.xyz_image_version
    }
  )
  filename = "${path.module}/descriptor.json"
}
```

The JSON template file (`descriptor.json.tpl`) would then have to look like:

```
{
  "service": "xyz",
  "external-resources": {
    "images":
    [
      {
        "name":"xyz_image",
        "version":"${image_version}"
      }
    ]
}
```

The `image_version` in the templated file is a placeholder variable which will be replaced by the value provided in the `templatefile` function call. The templated file will be used to create a file and save it locally in the module path with the name `descriptor.json`. You can add arbitrary number of variables to the templated file and as long as you provide the value for them in the function call, they will be replaced with that value. The JSON file can then be used as an input file where needed.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

Comment: Thanks for your input ! But somehow, I have to manage the json fiel format and way to maintain versions between TF file and JSON file.

Comment: Is there any way we can output "descriptor.json.tpl" as "descriptor.json" ? "descriptor.json" will have vslue "${image_version}"

Comment: `filename = "${path.module}/descriptor.json"` outputs a file which you can use in whatever the deployment is, but you haven't really explained what do you mean with deployment, so it's hard to come up with a guess.

Comment: We have other services deployment as well, now this descriptor.json is a metadata file that will be used by those other "services".  There are so many things connected but I will try to simplify. So, For example, there is jenkins job, which reads descriptor data (descriptor.json). And here "path_module" is module of infra-deployment and descriptor.json is in the infra-deployment root. I hope I m able to clarify. @MarkoE

Comment: So what is wrong with my answer then? Are you able to use the rendered file?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your answer. I will be trying approach you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Ah, ok, I was thinking that it does not work for you. :) Btw, you can store the resulting file anywhere on the filesystem where it could be used by Jenkins. Acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Once tested I will definitely accept. And again thanks a lot for your thorough input !!!

Comment: Hi Marko, one question, this TF local_file resource will create mentioned "filename" everytime or overwrite it. Is there any way to just "modify" given file without creating it? @Marko E

Comment: Not sure I understand what the issue is, but take a look here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file. If the file does not exist, terraform will recreate it each time. Please read the first note.

Comment: I did check the document. `filename = "${path.module}/descriptor.json"`
Here, if I use "local_file" TF resource, it will create above filename if not exists and if exists already it will override. Now, in my case as mentioned in question, I want to just pass `${image_version}` to JSON file. So my question was, without this creating/recreating everytime I appy TF changes, it should just modify my JSON file.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file
This can be also the solution